# Unanticipated Await/Async Behavior

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I'm trying to perform the following logic, in sequential/synchronous order via await/async.

```
async loadData() {


    console.log("STEP 1");
    let ratesResponse = await getRates();
    let accounts = realm.objects("Account");

    accounts.map(async account => {
      let accountResponse = await getAccountBalance(account.accountid);
      console.log("STEP 2");
      realm.write(() => {
        account.cad_balance = accountResponse.balances[0].value;
        account.usd_balance = (
          parseFloat(accountResponse.balances[0].value) *
          parseFloat(ratesResponse.last)
        ).toString();
      });
    });
    console.log("STEP 3");
    this.setState({
      data: realm.objects("Account"),
      last: ratesResponse.last,
      high: ratesResponse.high,
      low: ratesResponse.low,
      refreshing: false
    });

}
```

However, the app functionality doesn't work, and the logs confirm step 3 occurring prior to step 2:

```
2018-02-22 22:53:10.922 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] STEP 1
2018-02-22 22:53:10.921822-0500[13978:3180532] STEP 1
2018-02-22 22:53:11.211 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] STEP 3
2018-02-22 22:53:11.210787-0500[13978:3180532] STEP 3
2018-02-22 22:53:11.233 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] STEP 2
2018-02-22 22:53:11.233529-0500[13978:3180532] STEP 2
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It is working as you specified. The async callback in the .map() returns a promise. You must use `.then()` to `console.log('Step 3');`

Comment: What Arman Charan says works too. is probably closer to your design goals.  I lost sight of the `async()` waaaay up there. :-)

Comment: really? accounts.map returns a Promise you can await on?

Comment: you'll need to `await(Promise.all(accounts.map( ....` - and also, the `accounts.map` function actually needs to return something!! ... preferably a **Promise** to wait on!!

Comment: @JaromandaX technically if everything after the last `await` inside `map()` was synchronous (which I don't think is the case here, but still), then it doesn't actually need to return anything since the function is `async`.

Comment: No @PatrickRoberts that is not correct - correction, that is correct :p - I read what you said wrong :p

Comment: @JaromandaX The `map` callback is an async function so it does return a promise already. (One probably will need to await the `realm.write` thingy though)

Comment: I corrected myself - I read the comment all wrong :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map` doesn't await on the provided function, hence the await inside the provided function to `Array.prototype.map` does not cause the sync behaviour you expect.

You have two choices

1. Use the native `for in` operator that considers `await` in the block, like

   async loadData() {

   ```
   console.log("STEP 1");
   let ratesResponse = await getRates();
   let accounts = realm.objects("Account");

   for (let account in accounts) {
     let accountResponse = await getAccountBalance(account.accountid);
     console.log("STEP 2");
     realm.write(() => {
       account.cad_balance = accountResponse.balances[0].value;
       account.usd_balance = (
         parseFloat(accountResponse.balances[0].value) *
         parseFloat(ratesResponse.last)
       ).toString();
     });
   }
   console.log("STEP 3");
   this.setState({
     data: realm.objects("Account"),
     last: ratesResponse.last,
     high: ratesResponse.high,
     low: ratesResponse.low,
     refreshing: false
   });
   ```

   }
2. Or make await on the list of promises the async function returns like

   async loadData() {

   ```
   console.log("STEP 1");
   let ratesResponse = await getRates();
   let accounts = realm.objects("Account");

   await Promise.all(accounts.map(async (account) => {
     let accountResponse = await getAccountBalance(account.accountid);
     console.log("STEP 2");
     realm.write(() => {
       account.cad_balance = accountResponse.balances[0].value;
       account.usd_balance = (
         parseFloat(accountResponse.balances[0].value) *
         parseFloat(ratesResponse.last)
       ).toString();
     });
   });
   console.log("STEP 3");
   this.setState({
     data: realm.objects("Account"),
     last: ratesResponse.last,
     high: ratesResponse.high,
     low: ratesResponse.low,
     refreshing: false
   });
   ```

   }

However there is a subtile difference how these two will function, the first will process each account one by one, whereas the second will process all the accounts in parallel, but wait for the parallel execution to finish before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks @user2182269, I used the second option, works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

First thing - you'll need to await the array of promises returned by `accounts.map(async account => {...})`

This can be achieved using await Promise.all ... i.e. 
`Promise.all(accounts.map(async account => {...}))`

Second, if realm.write is **asynchronous**, you'll need to await a Promise that resolves when that function completes

```
await new Promise(resolve => realm.write(resolve));
```

So, putting it all together

```
async function loadData() {
    console.log('STEP 1');
    let ratesResponse = await getRates();
    let accounts = realm.objects('Account');
    await Promise.all(accounts.map(async account => {
        let accountResponse = await getAccountBalance(account.accountid);
        console.log('STEP 2');
        await new Promise(resolve => realm.write(resolve));
        account.cad_balance = accountResponse.balances[0].value;
        account.usd_balance = (parseFloat(accountResponse.balances[0].value) * parseFloat(ratesResponse.last)).toString();
    }));
    console.log('STEP 3');
    this.setState({
        data: realm.objects('Account'),
        last: ratesResponse.last,
        high: ratesResponse.high,
        low: ratesResponse.low,
        refreshing: false
    });
}
```

Comment: `return await` -> `return`. **Edit** Or, yeah. Just `await` works too.

Comment: d'oh!! buggered it up :p

Comment: Stupid firefox scratchpad screws up async/await/let etc when using pretty print!!!

Comment: @Bergi - interesting (and very good) edit! I simply assumed that a) realm.write was asynchronous, and b) somehow it affects the values of `accountResponse` etc (which, if it does, is an obscure function to be sure!!)

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, I don't know `realm.write`, I hope it's not using the callback as a transaction so that taking these statements outside would break them.

Answer (score 0):

`accounts.map(async() => ({}))` returns an array of promises.

You would then need to pass that array to `Promise.all()` and `await` for it.

Once all of those promises in that array resolve, it will then execute what's next which is your `console.log('STEP 3')`.

```
async function loadData() {
    console.log('STEP 1')
    const ratesResponse = await getRates()
    const accounts = realm.objects('Account')

    const promises = accounts.map(async (account) => {
        const accountResponse = await getAccountBalance(account.accountid)
        console.log('STEP 2')
        realm.write(() => {
            account.cad_balance = accountResponse.balances[0].value
            account.usd_balance = (
                parseFloat(accountResponse.balances[0].value) *
                parseFloat(ratesResponse.last)
            ).toString()
        })
    })

    await Promise.all(promises)

    console.log('STEP 3')
    this.setState({
        data: realm.objects('Account'),
        last: ratesResponse.last,
        high: ratesResponse.high,
        low: ratesResponse.low,
        refreshing: false,
    })
}
```

Comment: Two things. One, I would confirm that `realm.write()` is synchronous. I highly doubt it is. If not, you'll need to return a `Promise` that awaits on its completion from `accounts.map()`. Two, since the parent function is `async`, you should take advantage of that and convert `Promise.all(...).then(...)` to `await Promise.all(...); ...`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Good point. I don't know what `realm.write()` does though. I think the idea of the solution is here and the OP should be able to apply it.